# Naive Bayesian Classification (using NLTK)

Tags: python, class, types, classification, nltk

I'm trying to use Python's NLTK to do some answer type classification. Essentially train it on a bunch of questions then give some unseen questions.

The issue I'm having is that is pretty much just classifies any question as whichever is the most common answer type. So if there's 200 questions marked as 'people' and 150 marked as 'place' then EVERY test question is marked as having the answer type 'people'.

I know that balanced data is better, but it seems like a very tight restriction (as well as not feasible, given the amount of test data I'm using). The training data I'm using is this set of 5500 questions here:

http://cogcomp.cs.illinois.edu/Data/QA/QC/train_5500.label

And this is my Python code:

```
import nltk

train = []

with open('data.txt') as f:
    content = f.readlines()

for c in content:
    parts = c.split(' ', 1)
    train.append((dict(q=parts[1].rstrip()), parts[0]))


test = [
    (dict(q='When was the congress of Vienna?')),
    (dict(q='What is the capital of Australia?')),
    (dict(q='Why doesn\'t this classifier work?'))

]

classifier = nltk.classify.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(train)

print classifier.classify_many(test)
```

It assigns all 3 of the test questions the 'HUM:ind' class, which is the most common question in the training set. If I reduce the number of these HUM:ind questions, it then just starts saying it's the next most popular. It only takes a couple of questions of discrepancy before that answer type overpowers all the others.

Am I missing something? Am I not using the algorithm right? Is there some parameter I should change given the format of my training data? My example is pretty similar to a couple of examples I've seen online. Any help appreciated

Comment: Is this #homework ?

Comment: nah, it's for work

Comment: I would suggest to skip `nltk` and go direct to `sklearn`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always get the most frequent category back because you are not giving your classifier any useful features to work with: If you have to guess with no evidence at all, the most common class is the right answer.

The classifier can only reason about feature names and feature values it has seen before. (New data consists of known features in *combinations* that it has not seen before.) But your code only defines one "feature", `q`, and the value in each case is the entire text of the question. So all test questions are unknown (and therefore indistinguishable) feature values. You can't get something for nothing.

Learn [how to train a classifier](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch06.html), (and how classification works while you're at it), and the problem will go away.

Comment: Ohh I see, fair enough. But then what should I do for answer-type classification? I've only got one feature, the question.